# R Plot - Y Axis and plotted values are not correlated

Tags: r, plot, axis

I am somewhat new to R and I am trying to plot the following:

```
x <- c(1:13)
y <- c(19.77, 18.07, 20.55, 16.42, 18.47, 20.18, 22.91, 13.18, 18.07, 17.05, 13.45, 11.11, 22.52)
y2 <- c(26.93, 24.5, 25.73, 23.65, 20.50, 29.58, 18.8, 17.38, 12.2, 18.17, 12.55, 15.63, 26.07)
par(mar=c(5,7,5,3), pch=22, col="Black")
plot(x, y2, main="TITLE", xaxt = "n", xlab='', yaxt = "n", ylab = "", type="b", col="Blue")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, y, xaxt = "n", xlab='', yaxt = "n", ylab = "", type="b", col="cyan", pch=21)
range <- seq(0, 30, 1)
axis(1, at=x, labels=x)
axis(2, at=range, labels=range, las=1)
mtext(side = 1, text = "X", line = 3, col="Black")
mtext(side = 2, text = "Tiempo", line = 5, xpd=FALSE, col="Black")
# Legend.
legend(x= "bottomleft", y=0.92, legend=c("Exp1","Exp2"), col=c("cyan", "blue"), pch=c("_","_"))
```

It plots OK, as follows:

[image: My plot]

However, I feel that the y axis is not correlating to the real values. For example, in the data (y and y2) we can see that one of the maximum values is 26.93 but in the data, the highest value is around to 23 according to the plot.

I have been playing with the range variable but I still haven't found any way to correct this. Google has been of no help since I am not sure about how should I search for this problem. Does any of you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Also, I want the values to range from 0 to 30, not from 11 to 23. Maybe this is related to the problem.

Any tip would be valuable! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Funny, you have 13 x values and 13 tick marks on the y-axis.  I would immediately infer without looking at the code that you remapped the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying as close as possible to your code, you could change lines #5 and #7 like this:

```
plot(y2 ~ x,  main="TITLE", xaxt = "n", xlab='', yaxt = "n", ylab = "", type = "b", col = "Blue", ylim = c(0,30))
lines(y ~ x, xaxt = "n", xlab = '', yaxt = "n", ylab = "", type = "b", col = "cyan", pch = 21)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `matplot`:

```
matplot(x, cbind(y2,y), t='b', col = c("blue", "cyan"), pch = c(22, 21), lty = c(1,1),　xaxt = "n", xlab="", yaxt = "n", ylab = "")
axis(1, at=x, labels=x)
axis(2, at=range, labels=range, las=1)
mtext(side = 1, text = "X", line = 3, col="Black")
mtext(side = 2, text = "Tiempo", line = 5, xpd=FALSE, col="Black")
legend(x= "bottomleft", y=0.92, legend=c("Exp1","Exp2"), col=c("cyan", "blue"), pch=c("_","_"))
```

[image]